# Problems with UISwipeGestureRecognizer, UITapGestureRecognizer and MPMoviePlayerController :-(

Tags: ipad, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, uigesturerecognizer

This has me completely stumped!

I have a Tap Gesture Recognizer for show/hide menus...

I also have a Swipe Gesture Recognizer for swiping left and right between screens...

I then also have an MPMoviePlayerController for playing back video on the screen.

I am implementing `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` and excluding all UIControls and anything that has the prefix "MP".

Problem is, whenever I swipe left and right on the movie player controls, the `shouldReceiveTouch` only notices the Tap Gesture Recognizer, NOT the swipe one. It also traces NO correctly, and yet STILL triggers the swipe method.

I've tried looking at `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer` but that's just REALLY confused me, because it also contains a UIPanGestureRecognizer... Where did THAT come from?

Please help, I am tired and have a big deadline... and can't work it out :(

Thank you all!

:-Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I must apologise... The reason it wasn't receiving `shouldReceiveTouch` messages was because I wasn't setting its delegate!! What a numpty. I was setting the delegate for the tap gesture, but not the swipe one. Now it's all working fine.

Sorry! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'd the same problem.
Here's what I did to overcome the problem.
In the [self doSomething...] methods I do some animation and if the animation finishes
it sets the enabled state of the recognizer back to YES.
Be aware of the fact, that you set the correct recognizer back to enabled! (here I have
to (left/right), so the gestureRecognizers array has 2 entries.

```
- (void)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && recognizer.enabled) {
        recognizer.enabled = NO;
        if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
        {
            [self doSomethingInteresting];
        }
        else {
            [self doSomethingElseInteresting];
        }
    }
}
```

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.containerView
          duration:kAnimationDuration
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
         animations:^{ your animations }
         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                if (self.containerView.gestureRecognizers.count) {
             ((UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)[self.containerView.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]).enabled = YES;
} }];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but unfortunately I am already removing the gesture recognizers during the animation and adding them again. In fact, I have to do that rather than setting the "enabled" property, which messes up the views and makes them go completely blank for some reason! I am on 3.2 so I can't use blocks unfortunately either. But the problem seems to be coming from the fact that my "shouldReceiveTouch" delegate method isn't receiving any swipe information, only tap :-(

Comment: Incidentally, could you please explain to me how you are using one gesture recognizer for both swipe left and right? I tried doing that originally but when I receive the message to the selector I couldn't find any way of finding which direction it came from... recognizer.direction just returns both...